# Get substring of a string in korn shell

Tags: unix, ksh

I have to extract a substring using ksh88. (BTW the simple way of finding the version of ksh `$KSH_VERSION` is not working for me. I had to use

```
 [ "`echo "\c" | grep c`" ] && echo ksh93 || echo ksh88
```

I tried using the command `echo ${stringvariable : 2: 2}` But it says `bad substitution`. I am new to the Unix world. This is what I did to get the result:

I've logged into Unix using PUTTY and typed the above command. I also tried first ksh command, then my command but still no success. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Also if I want the substring till end starting from position 2 how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whitespace is significant in the shell. You should use

```
$ stringvariable="foobar"
$ echo ${stringvariable:2:2}
ob
```

*Note: This works on **ksh93**, It won't work with **ksh88**.*

If your words are space separated, you can use `set`:

```
$ stringvariable="foo bar baz zap"
$ set -- $stringvariable
$ echo $3
baz
```

This should **always** be preferred over useless forks of `cut`. Using `cut` to get at characters in a string is the programming equivalent of using a 40 ton truck to buy and transport a piece of cube sugar.

Comment: doesnt work :(  same error. bad substitution. The second option works well. But could you explain what does the second line "set --" does ?

Comment: @user Yes it does work, and I provided the evidence. If it doesn't work for you, you are not using a current ksh. The `set` command sets the positional parameters. The stringvariable is split at the characters in `IFS` (usually blank, newline, tab) and then assigned to $1 etc.

Comment: thanks @Jens. as mentioned in the question i have ksh88. Even i dont know why its not working for me.

Comment: @user1016198 That explains it. It was ksh93 which introduced substring extraction, see http://www.kornshell.com/doc/ksh93.html

Comment: @mlwacosmos Is your shell a ksh93? It won't work with ksh88.

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution which worked for me. Could not find why the solution in the question itself is not working.

Here is what worked for me:

```
str1="get word from this-text"
```

## get second word. -d is the delimiter(here space)

```
str2=`echo $str1 | cut -d" " -f 2`

echo $str2
word
```

## get 3 chars starting at 5th

```
str2=`echo $str1 | cut -b 5-3`
echo $str2
wor
```